# https redirect (with .htaccess) redirect loop

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https

There are quite a few threads going on regarding this but they all seem to say the same thing (which I tried) but I keep getting a redirect loop.
I already tried changing the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in the General settings (my admin panel is already on https)

My .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# start https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# end https redirect

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd steer clear on editing the `.htaccess` if you're just updating your website from HTTP to HTTPS. Try an alternative route:

First, revert your `.htaccess` back to the default settings:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Next, you need to ensures that all of the URLs for your website are up-to-date, try the following steps using the [Search Replace DB tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/):

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://web.site/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your HTTPS link in the **`search for…`** field and the new HTTPS link in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

#### However...

If you still insist on having your HTTP redirect to HTTPS via the `.htaccess` add the following in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

It should look like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

# start https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# end https redirect

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks but your suggestion does not do anything (no redirect to https but also doesn't break anything)

Comment: Ok, Can you try by moving "RewriteBase /" line above to https code and below to "RewriteEngine On".

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing anything :(